# jQuery UI range slider plugin conflicts with jQuery Mobile slider

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to get jQuery range slider working with jQuery Mobile but it seems like it's conflicting with each other and when I use `$('#something').slider()` it uses jQuery Mobile's slider instead.

However jQuery Mobile does not have dual range slider which is why I need to use jQuery UI.

Is there a way we can get this working so range is working? or is there another jQuery Plugin that you can recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how I solved it. The JQuery UI page allows you to do selective download. I removed the tick for "Slider" and downloaded the new javascript. Now my slider comes from JQuery Mobile itself. Hope this helps.